# How can I make a Gantt chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, gantt-chart

I'm trying to produce a chart similar to a Gantt chart which effectively shows 1 line of information for all tasks, by teams within a project.

[This link](http://www.mediafire.com/?k5ms4a99o856crj,3q4xn4x24m70p6c,h0sbe6h4lu206) includes:

- An linked image showing what I'm looking to achieve.
- A  worksheet that allows me to generate the image using some software called Tableau. However, ideally I want to be able to do something similar with excel 2010 as Tableau server costs a bomb.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tons of examples found via Google - did you try any of them?

Comment: I looked through google but didn't find anything of use... I'm not a good googler though...

Comment: You don't have to be very good - try "gantt chart excel" :)  Here's one result worth checking: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/GanttChart.html

Answer (score 4):

The new databars/sparklines features provide nice ways to do Gantt Charts and resource histograms, here’s a sample:

[image]

One way to achieve this is first set up your table, called A say, then to create the databars, set the min and max formulas equal to defined names Min:=MIN(A[Start])-A[@Start] and Max:=MAX(A[End])-A[@Start]+1.

You can copy down individually with the format painter to propagate. After create a separate range for the resources and add a column sparkline to a cell as shown.